# Cannot access POST service hosted locally on Nodejs from angular $http method

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http-post

I have a POST api service hosted locally on nodejs server which I want to access from my angualrJS code, but I am getting an error in console as
POST http://10.176.1.85:4242/createUser?action=add net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

my Node js code is

```
app.post('/createUser', function(req, res) {

   connection.connect(function(err) {
    // ... error checks 
    console.dir(err);
    // Query 

    var request = new sql.Request();
    console.dir(request);
    console.dir(req.body);
    request.query("insert into dbo.Users (username,password,emailId) values ('" + req.body.username + "','" + req.body.password + "','" + req.body.email + "')", function(err, recordset,fields) {
        // ... error checks 

        console.dir(recordset);
        res.send(200);
     // res.send(err+recordset+fields+req.body.username+req.body.password+req.body.email);
     //connection.close();
    });



});
```

});

and my angular code to access this is

```
$http({
                        method: "post",
                        url: "http://localhost:4242/createUser",
                        params: {
                            action: "add"
                        },
                        data: {
                            name: userDetails
                        }
                    }).then(function (response) {

                        return "Done";
                    }, function(error) {
                        return q.reject(error.data);
                    });
```

Comment: first of all, `http://10.176.1.85:4242/createUser?action=add` looks like a GET request to me.. also, did you check whether the app is actually listening on that host/port? There're several rest api clients to test it, for example..

Comment: Thanks John. Actually the error is  http://localhost:4242/createUser?actiotion=add. and its a POST request since I am sending the data in the POST request. Moreover when I write a get request in the same file and access it through browser,then it works fine for me and I get the response on the browser.

Comment: it worked fine for me after using bodyparser.                                                    app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));